# How can I simulate Enums that can be expanded at Runtime in Java?

Tags: java, class, enums

I am writing a program to simulate cities from a game called Civilization 4. In order to do this I have several Enums to represent types of terrain, resources, improvements etc for each plot owned by said city.

The problem is I want to program to be compatible with Fan made mods which may add things to the Game that need to be accepted into my independant utility. So I thought of creating a Enum *style* class to hold the new types defined by the loaded mods (as Enums cannot be changed at runtime) which is created during runtime when the user enters in a mod to be loaded (which is a txt file that is parsed to read the new additions)

So is there a way to simulate Enums that are created and added to **at runtime**? I take it static member variables cannot be used as they are done before runtime...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `enum` implement an interface.

This way you can have your defined values in the enum, but new values can be any class which implements the interface.

---

An alternative is that you generate or load the `enum` at runtime using a byte code generator or the Compiler API.  I wrote a library to make it easier to take a String and compile&load it.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2010_11_01_archive.html

Comment: Interesting... I take it that the class implementing the interface doesn't add to the enums but serves as a outside storage?

Comment: Correct, this allows you to mix and match.

Answer (score 1):

Well, enums in Java are simply classes where the language guarantees that the set of known objects is known and limited at compile-time. If you want to add new enum literals at runtime, you end up with regular classes.

Comment: Thats fine for me. I have my set of Enums for the default stuff and a Set of classes to store Runtime stuff. But how would I add stuff to a class at runtime? When I think about it I could have the class object become the enum where all objects are tied up to the class (I think this is possible with python, not sure how to do it in Java though)

Comment: I don't understand why you can just have a regular class with a bunch of static members for the "pre-defined" instances and then create new instances of that class at runtime? The point of having an enum is that you are guaranteed that you know the set of values in advance.

Comment: because that means remoddeling everything :p

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of enums is that you can write human readable names in code that are compiled as numbers behind the scenes, because computers like numbers better. Take for example this enum:

```
enum Season { WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, AUTUMN }
```

Behind the scenes WINTER might be 0 (zero), SPRING is 1 etc.
To replicate this behaviour in runtime code you could create a list of strings, like this:

```
List<String> seasons;
seasons = new ArrayList<String>();
seasons.add("Winter");
seasons.add("Spring");
...
```

That way you can reference the items as numbers, such as seasons[1] would equal "Spring". 
This answer is just one of many ways to approach this question.

Comment: Ahh you just solved a problem that would arise in the future. The user needs to see the Enums on the interface, instances or numbers wounldn't cut it! Nice answer :D

Answer (score 1):

By default, `enum` types have only a set number of values. The values in an `enum` type are actually declared as `static final`, and there's no way to add more on runtime.

That being said, there are other patterns you can use to implement what you want. Let's take a look at using an interface and a registration system. We'll start with the `Terrain` interface:

```
public interface Terrain {
    int getId();
    String getName();
    int getSightBonus();
}
```

Now an `enum`, `DefaultTerrain`:

```
public enum DefaultTerrain implements Terrain {
    PLAINS(0, "Plains", 1),
    HILLS(1, "Hills", -1),
    MOUNTAINS(2, "Mountains", -2);

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int sightBonus;

    private DefaultTerrain(int id, String name, int sightBonus) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.sightBonus = sightBonus;
    }

    public int getId() {return id;}

    public String getName() {return name;}

    public int getSightBonus() {return sightBonus;}
}
```

And a registration class, which can be either a static utility class or a singleton.

```
public class TerrainManager {
    private static Map<Integer, Terrain> terrainsById = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (DefaultTerrain terrain : DefaultTerrain.values())
            register(terrain);
    }

    public static void register(Terrain terrain) {
        Integer id = terrain.getId();
        if (terrainsById.contains(terrain.getId()))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Terrain with id already exists: " + id);
        terrainsById.put(id, terrain);
    }

    public static Terrain getTerrainById(int id) {
        return terrainsById.get(id);
    }

    public static Set<Terrain> getAllTerrains() {
        return new HashSet<Terrain>(terrainsById.values());
    }
}
```

This last class is where the magic happens. Presumably the modders will have some kind of identifier in the game's world definition to say "use this tile," right? In this case, I've called it an integer, `id`, but really it could be any type, just modify the `Map` accordingly. In the map-loading code, just use the ID in the world definition to look up the `Terrain`. When a modder adds a new `Terrain`, they just need to implement `Terrain` and register it with `TerrainManager`.

The `static` initializer makes sure that your `DefaultTerrain` objects are added before anything else is added. If you use a singleton, this could be put into the class constructor instead.

Use this pattern for your different `enum` types that you want users to add to. You could also use it for pretty much any other type as well besides `enum`.

Comment: Fantastic answer!
does seem like a good way to do it. if only operator overloading was present in Java I could make the TerrainsManager class overload [] to directly access an Enum. In game the terrains are actually defined in the XML by... Enums! So your ID would probably emulate that by being a string. Awesome suggestion though, I thought about using this sort of method myself about half an hour ago. Would take a long sort recoding to get the current code to adapt but worth it!

Answer (score 0):

You will need CGLIB, http://cglib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used a third party library before, I take it I just put it in with my source files and include as normal (because I don't want my Users to go and have to fidn and install somethign extra).